# Widget kit not working for joomla 1. 7

Tags: joomla

I have a joomla 1. 7 website and I have installed a widget kit for displaying a slider with buttons on it. It works fine in the backend, however it does not display on the site.

Is there a reason why widget kit is not compatible with Joomla 1. 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any details at all, I'd suggest a possible conflict with you chosen joomla template and javascript library(s) like jquery or mootools.

Try one of the simple templates that came with your joomla installation and see if the problem on the front end persists.

Answer (score 1):

Widget Kit is compatible with Joomla 1.7, however as Grag P said, it might possibly be a conflict with another extension using Jquery.

1. Use Firebug and look at the scripts being loaded in the `<head>` tags and see if there are 2 Jquery libraries being loaded.
2. If so then the 2nd one is most likely coming from your template in which case go to your template manager and see if there is an option to turn off Jquery, else if its coming from another extension, try disabling it and seeing if this solves the problem.

Also make sure you have the most up-to-date version of widget kit as Yootheme have brought out a lot of updates in the last 2 months.